# htaccess URL rewriting meaning

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am new url rewriting therefore can anybody please explain me the meaning of the below two lines.. especially the [R=permanent,QSA,L]

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cid=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(ed)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/rrc.php?cid=%1 [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permanent redirection. If the user-agent have got the cookie **cid**, he'll append it as an URL parameter.

R give the redirection code.
QSA mean to append request query string.